# Rotational force upon springs

Tags: torque, spring, elasticity

Is there any model which can help determine how much a string will contract if it is acted upon by a force which causes a torque?

Can we also create a model of Hooke's law which tells the relation between the torque acted[image] upon the spring and the contraction of the spring.

Suppose that the circle is cross sectional area of the spring.

Comment: Rotate in which direction?

Comment: i have just added a image so you can visualize it better.

Comment: When you say "suppose circle is cross sectional area of a spring" do you mean looking at the spring from the top down, or is that a side view of one of the coils in the spring?

Comment: looking at the spring from top down.

Comment: Okay, I was just curious, because when you push down on a spring like normal, every coil will be twisting like that from a side view (interestingly a coil spring is essentially just a bar that you twist, only it's coiled so that the twisting results in a net up-down motion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some springs which do this as a primary method of movement, called [torsion springs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_spring).  Those have a equations for Hooke's law that relates to the change in angle between the two ends (it also requires knowing the spring constant, or calculating it based on the geometry of the spring, which is more complicated).  I'm not sure if that helps you.

What happens to the area and length of the spring when you twist one end relative to the other is a bit more complicated.  I doubt there is a simple linear relationship like there is with Hooke's Law.